# Getting BufferOverflowException with MediaCodec encode data

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

I am using `Camera2` API to get data from a camera, then using Image reader, `OnImageAvailableListener` implementation, I insert the camera data into a queue, then using new `MediaCodec.Callback` implementation I want to encode the data

This is how I init the codec:

```
MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, cameraRawData.getSize().getWidth(), cameraRawData.getSize().getHeight());
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, COLOR_FormatSurface);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2000000);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
format.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, Long.MAX_VALUE);
try {
    encoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error creating encoder", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The `onInputBufferAvailable` implementation:

```
ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
ImageData imageData = imageDataQueue.poll();

if (imageData != null) {
    if (inputBuffer != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable: " + imageData.getBuffer().length);
        inputBuffer.clear();
        byte[] bytes = imageData.getBuffer();
        try {
            Log.w(TAG, "before failure, the limit is: " + inputBuffer.limit());
            Log.w(TAG, "before failure, the byte array size is: " + bytes.length);
            inputBuffer.put(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error", e);
        }
        codec.queueInputBuffer(index,
                0,
                imageData.getBuffer().length,
                imageData.getPresentationTimeUs(),
                0);
    }
} else {
    codec.queueInputBuffer(index,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0);
}
```

and eventually, the exception I receive:

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:298)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:732)
```

Some additional information, the ByteBuffer limit is set to 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of debug, the issue was wrong color format.
Instead of:

```
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, COLOR_FormatSurface);
```

It should have been:

```
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible);
```

Comment: mark your answer as valid, it solved the issue  and will help future users, don't be shy ;)